# Finding out names like & , and in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, data-modeling

I have a table where I would need to find out ampersand, and in between names. i have tried using like operator but it doesn't work.
ex: select name from t1 where name like('%&%','%and%')
Ampersands works in this case but and doesn't work there could be scenario where name=candy,sandy,anderson,randy this is a match in that case and I only need records
where abc&xyz, abcandXYZ

Comment: Are you sure you are on SQL Server? It does work when I try it

Comment: Given your requirements, this seems impossible. You say you do want to return the value "abdandXYZ", but not return the value "candy". From your point of view, what is the difference between these two? If the answer is that "as a human, the word 'candy' looks like someone's name, but the word "abcandXYZ" does not, well, ok, but how do you expect a computer to know that? What if someone named their child "abcandXYZ"?

Comment: Once you correct your SQL, as I showed, you still need to restrict your requirement, so that the patterns match only the cases you really intended.  With the complete requirement, we should be able to adjust the patterns.

Comment: Remember the names Frank Zappa chose for his kids?  "Moon Unit", "Dweezil", and "Diva Thin Muffin"

Comment: @JonArmstrong "X Æ A-12 Musk"

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Sample data, expected results and a clear explanation of your code and where it is failing help us help you. It appears that you want to match _words_, not _strings_. If so, you need to be able to define the rules for separating words.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways.  The main problem with your `LIKE` attempt is `LIKE` takes a single pattern, not a list of patterns.  An easy approach is just this:

```
SELECT name
  FROM t1
 WHERE name LIKE '%&%'
    OR name LIKE '%and%'
;
```

Here's a quick way to test:

```
WITH t1 (name) AS (
        SELECT 'xxx&bbb' AS str UNION
        SELECT 'xxxandbbb'
     )
SELECT name
  FROM t1
 WHERE name LIKE '%&%'
    OR name LIKE '%and%'
;
```

Result:

[image]

Here's a test case showing both queries:

[Working test case, with error in the original, plus the solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=50d3e3d81741efca68e298d33c3486d3)

You could also use a regular expression pattern to match both, with a different operator.

Comment: thanks for you reply but in my case if i use like '%and%' then i would get a name randy ,sandy, pandy,andy, these are actual fullnames but i need only records which have abcandxyz , xyzandabc

Comment: @rinku Sure, but you haven't yet provided any way to tell the difference between something you want and something you don't want.  How do we know which cases you really want?  Can you define the strict meaning of `full name`?  Do you have a list of `full names` in your database with which we can search?